# How to fetch WooCommerce's variation images of products?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a code which I basically use to create a request to my WordPress site and as an response I am getting the response that includes product data.
I basically do get in variation's object properties like SKU, price and similar to that right.
But the main problem is that I am not getting the urls of images (which I do expect to get).

Here's the example of object that I get:

```
{
    "id": 4074,
    "title": "S008",
    "price": "",
    "short_description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amanet",
    "sku": "",
    "variations": [
        {
            "id": 12951,
            "title": "S008<span> &#8211; </span>Black, M/L",
            "price": "25",
            "sku": "040071",
            "images": []
        },
        {
            "id": 12952,
            "title": "S008<span> &#8211; </span>Red, M/L",
            "price": "25",
            "sku": "040072",
            "images": []
        },
        {
            "id": 12953,
            "title": "S008<span> &#8211; </span>White, M/L",
            "price": "25",
            "sku": "040073",
            "images": []
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/s_0008_S008-black-back-zoom.webp"
    ]
}
```

In my functions.php I have included this code:

```
// my-api-plugin.php

// Enqueue necessary scripts and stylesheets
function my_api_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-api-script', plugins_url('my-api-plugin/js/my-api-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_api_enqueue_scripts');

// Register custom API route
function my_api_register_routes() {
    register_rest_route('my-api/v1', '/products', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_api_get_products',
    ));
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'my_api_register_routes');

// Callback function to retrieve product data
function my_api_get_products($request) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $products = get_posts($args);

    $response = array();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_data = array(
            'id' => $product->ID,
            'title' => get_the_title($product->ID),
            'price' => get_post_meta($product->ID, '_regular_price', true),
            'short_description' => get_the_excerpt($product->ID),
            'sku' => get_post_meta($product->ID, '_sku', true),
            'variations' => array(),
            'images' => array(),
        );

        // Get images for the product
        $product_images = get_post_meta($product->ID, '_product_image_gallery', true);
        if ($product_images) {
            $product_images = explode(',', $product_images);
            foreach ($product_images as $image_id) {
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full');
                if ($image_url) {
                    $product_data['images'][] = $image_url;
                }
            }
        }

        // Get variations if available
        if ($product->post_type === 'product_variation') {
            $parent_product_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($product->ID);
            $parent_product = get_post($parent_product_id);

            if ($parent_product) {
                $product_data['title'] = get_the_title($parent_product->ID);
                $product_data['price'] = get_post_meta($parent_product->ID, '_regular_price', true);
                $product_data['short_description'] = get_the_excerpt($parent_product->ID);
                $product_data['sku'] = get_post_meta($parent_product->ID, '_sku', true);
                $product_data['images'] = array();

                // Get images for the parent product
                $parent_product_images = get_post_meta($parent_product->ID, '_product_image_gallery', true);
                if ($parent_product_images) {
                    $parent_product_images = explode(',', $parent_product_images);
                    foreach ($parent_product_images as $image_id) {
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full');
                        if ($image_url) {
                            $product_data['images'][] = $image_url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Add variations data if available
        if ($product->post_type === 'product' && $product->post_parent === 0) {
            $variations = get_children(array(
                'post_parent' => $product->ID,
                'post_type' => 'product_variation',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'asc',
                'numberposts' => -1,
            ));

            foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                $variation_data = array(
                    'id' => $variation->ID,
                    'title' => get_the_title($variation->ID),
                    'price' => get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_regular_price', true),
                    'sku' => get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_sku', true),
                    'images' => array(),
                );

                // Get images for the variation
                $variation_images = get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_product_image_gallery', true);
                if ($variation_images) {
                    $variation_images = explode(',', $variation_images);
                    foreach ($variation_images as $image_id) {
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full');
                        if ($image_url) {
                            $variation_data['images'][] = $image_url;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $product_data['variations'][] = $variation_data;
            }
        }

        $response[] = $product_data;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Make an AJAX request to retrieve the products
  $.ajax({
    url: '/wp-json/my-api/v1/products',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      // Handle the response data
      if (response.length > 0) {
        // Create an array to store the processed product data
        var products = [];

        // Loop through each product
        $.each(response, function(index, product) {
          // Access the product data
          var productId = product.id;
          var title = product.title;
          var price = product.price;
          var shortDescription = product.short_description;
          var sku = product.sku;
          var variations = product.variations;
          var images = product.images;


          // Create an object to store the processed product information
          var processedProduct = {
            id: productId,
            title: title,
            price: price,
            shortDescription: shortDescription,
            sku: sku,
            variations: variations,
            images: images
          };

          // Add the processed product to the products array
          products.push(processedProduct);
        });

        // Use the products array as needed in your application
        console.log('Products:', products);
      } else {
        console.log('No products found.');
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log('AJAX Error:', error);
    }
  });
});
```

I tried searching upon the [WooCommerce Product Variations REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-variation-image-properties) and I've tried changing the name and using "image" instead of "images" here:

```
// Get variations if available
        if ($product->post_type === 'product_variation') {
            $parent_product_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($product->ID);
            $parent_product = get_post($parent_product_id);

            if ($parent_product) {
                $product_data['title'] = get_the_title($parent_product->ID);
                $product_data['price'] = get_post_meta($parent_product->ID, '_regular_price', true);
                $product_data['short_description'] = get_the_excerpt($parent_product->ID);
                $product_data['sku'] = get_post_meta($parent_product->ID, '_sku', true);
                $product_data['images'] = array();

                // Get images for the parent product
                $parent_product_images = get_post_meta($parent_product->ID, '_product_image_gallery', true);
                if ($parent_product_images) {
                    $parent_product_images = explode(',', $parent_product_images);
                    foreach ($parent_product_images as $image_id) {
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full');
                        if ($image_url) {
                            $product_data['images'][] = $image_url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But still can't figure it out.

Update 27.5: Still not able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically I've found out the answer to this, and I changed code so that the $variation_image_id variable is now fetched using the _thumbnail_id meta key instead of variation_image_gallery.